# How to accept socket.io connection from an android client in Sails server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

We have an android client which sends a socket connect request to the Node JS server. While using **Express JS**, this is the code which accepts the connection (copied from [chat application example](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

This is working as expected and we are getting 'a user connected' log in the console. But when we try to accept the connection request in our **Sails JS** server, it is not working. In Sails, we are using `sails.io`. Here is the code:

```
sails.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

We added the above code in the `app.js` file. But it was not working. Is this the right way to accept a connection in a Sails server? If not, how do we do that?

Comment: Not yet. But If you have any idea, can I accept a normal socket request using sails sockets?

Comment: which client library are you using ?

Comment: We are using [socket.io-client.java](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java)